# i can't load data from mongoDB using Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

I can't load data from MongoDB using Angular 8.

I've done it with https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ and it is working, but locally 'http://localhost:3000/employees' it does not.

I post data but i can't it how can i solve this problem pls !!!

Dashboard service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Employee } from '../models/Employee.model';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class DashboardService {

   //Url get data
    serviceUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/employees';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

//get Employees
    getEmployee(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.serviceUrl);

    }
}
```

Component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardService } from '../services/dashboard.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dashboardService : DashboardService){}
  Employee :any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getEmployee()
    .subscribe(data => this.Employee = data)
    console.log(this.dashboardService)

  }
}
```

server side :

```
const express = require ('express');    
const router = express.Router();    
const Employee = require ('../models/employee');

router.get('/employees', async (req, res)=>{
    try {
        let employees = await Employee.find();

        res.status(200).json({
            employees : employees
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err.message
        })
    }
});
```

server side :

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require ('mongoose');
const dotenv = require ('dotenv');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require ('cors');


dotenv.config();

const app = express();

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE,
     { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: true, useCreateIndex: true }, err =>{
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to the DataBase.....')
    }
});


app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) =>{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Header', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});

const routesAdmin = require ('./routes/admin');
const routesAnswer = require ('./routes/answers');
const routesEmployee = require ('./routes/employee');
const routesSala = require ('./routes/sala');
const routesTavolo = require ('./routes/tavolo');



app.use('/api', routesAdmin);
app.use('/api', routesAnswer);
app.use('/api', routesEmployee);
app.use('/api', routesSala);
app.use('/api', routesTavolo);


app.listen(process.env.PORT, err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }else{
        console.log('Server is running..', process.env.PORT);
    }
});
```

Comment: why are you logging dashboardservice? Shouldn't you log data?

Comment: It seems like your problem is originating from your backend (which you have posted here) and not from the angular side assuming with a JSON placeholder everything worked as expected as you said.

Comment: Is there any errors in the console?

Comment: @tomslabbaert i posted now

Comment: @Sachin nothing

Comment: Can you also share the index.js (or server or app)  of your node app?

Comment: @SuleymanSah i posted it

Comment: Amine you are using same values here in the index js,  change them:  like `app.use('/api/admins', routesAdmin);`   `app.use('/api/answers', routesAnswer)`;

Comment: Amine check my answer please.

Comment: @SuleymanSah nothing

Comment: ` 
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead >
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">surname</th>
        <th scope="col">name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let employee of employees">
        <td>{{employee.username}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
      </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same route url `"/api"` for all your routes here:

```js
app.use('/api', routesAdmin);
app.use('/api', routesAnswer);
app.use('/api', routesEmployee);
app.use('/api', routesSala);
app.use('/api', routesTavolo);
```

You need to use different urls in your index.js so that routing can work as expected:

```js
app.use('/api/admins', routesAdmin);
app.use('/api/answers', routesAnswer);
app.use('/api/employees', routesEmployee);
app.use('/api/sala', routesSala);
app.use('/api/tavolo', routesTavolo);
```

And in your employees router (and also in the other routes), you don't need to add employees to the url:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res)=>{ ...
```

Now you need to be able to get data when you send a GET request to this url `http://localhost:3000/api/employees`

I suggest you to test the api first with postman, and after you see it is working, proceed to integrate to the react app.

Also change your DashboarService definition like this:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DashboardService {

   //Url get data
    serviceUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/employees';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    //get Employees
    getEmployee(): Observable<Employee[]> {
        return this.http.get<Employee[]>(this.serviceUrl);
    }
}
```

And also add this error case in your component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DashboardService } from "../services/dashboard.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-dashboard",
  templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.component.css"]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dashboardService: DashboardService) {}
  Employee: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardService.getEmployee().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Data: ", data);
        this.Employee = data;
      },
      err => {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: @amine did you changed all the 5 routes url in the index.js? Also please test your api first with postman.

Comment: i tested with Postman, everything is working well, but from angular nothing `app.use('/api/admins', routesAdmin);
app.use('/api/feedback', routesAnswer);
app.use('/api/employees', routesEmployee);
app.use('/api/sala', routesSala);
app.use('/api/tavolo', routesTavolo);`

Comment: @amine what does your employees api return? Does it return an array of employee document?

Comment: @amine I also made a change to DashboarService, can you check it? And open   network tab in the browser developer tools, and control if your get request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your are returning all the employees from the server side and you have wrapped it to another variable called "employees".

```
let employees = await Employee.find();

    res.status(200).json({
        employees : employees
    });
```

And from your angular side you are only looking for employee objects. So modify your code as like below,

```
res.status(200).json(employees);
```

Comment: i implemented that but, nothing

Comment: So are you able to log all the employee details from the nodejs side?